# keep tab content on refresh using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am currently making a menu bar for my school project the problem is, whenever the page is reloaded, it will always be redirected to the first menu content even if you are on the third menu.

HTML file: `index.php`:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="header-link">
        <li data-content='Home'>HOME</li>
        <li data-content='ContactUs'>Contact Us</li>
        <li data-content='Login'>Login</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="link-content"></div>
```

JavaScript file: `script.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Content/'+$(this).data('content')+'.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#link-content').html(response);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: You could play with the browser history and add url parameters. These can be evaluated with js for loading the correct content

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API If you need to support IE 9, use local storage or php Sessions

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to set session or cookie to your web browser with current menu you was selected. After that you can verify condition with session with current active page.

Here is the javascript code to set session to browser:

sessionStorage.setItem('active_menu', 'Your_Current_page');

Comment: You can use active class on current selected menu item.

Comment: @PHPGeek of course he can use active class on html tab

Answer (score 0):

I use your code as example and try to set the cookie as `tabIndex` and while you click on the specific `li` and get the success response in AJAX i just set the cookie value and added `class=active` in that particular `li`.

While you refresh your page, if found the cookie value then simply add `class=active` in the specific `li`.

Please try this code.

> index.php

```
<div id="header">
  <ul id="header-link">
    <li data-content='Home'>HOME</li>
    <li data-content='ContactUs'>Contact Us</li>
    <li data-content='Login'>Login</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="link-content"></div>
```

> script.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    if(getCookie('tabIndex') != '' && getCookie('tabIndex') != 'undefined'){
        $('#header-link li').each(function(i) { 
           if($(this).attr('data-content') == getCookie('tabIndex')){
                $(this).addClass('active');
           }
        });
    }

    $('li').click(function() {
        var currentElement = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Content/'+$(this).data('content')+'.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#header-link li').removeClass('active');
                document.cookie = "tabIndex=" + currentElement.attr('data-content');
                currentElement.addClass('active');
                $('#link-content').html(response);
            }
        })
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this answer useful to you? @enthusiast